# Using canvas rectangles as buttons to create menus and actions

Tags: button, tkinter, canvas, arguments

I am programing a GUI for a device that contains numerous sensors... I need to display their information accordingly... Some of them will require manual input which I want to input via using multiple rectangles used as menu items and adding a tag_bind to them to take action upon being clicked.

If you read carefully... I have attempted to erase the menu that has been pressed so it is not displayed after it is pressed. ( or at least at the last click, go back to only showing the main menu
I am running into an issue with the arguments... I little bit of help would be appreciated.

*error: in onSecondClick
canvas.delete(square)
NameError: global name 'square' is not defined*

I am able to delete the main menu rectangle but doesn't delete any other... I am a bit stomped

```
   from Tkinter import * 
    #global square
    def onObjectClick(event):
    #.   print(event.x, event.y)
         square = canvas.create_rectangle(40, 50, 150, 100, width=1, fill="#BBB", tags="secondtag")
         squaretxt = canvas.create_text(90,70, text="Sub-Menu")
         canvas.delete(mainbutton)
         canvas.delete(mainbuttontxt)
    
    def onSecondClick(square, *args):
    #    print(event.x, event.y) 
         secondsquare = canvas.create_rectangle(60,70,160,110, width=1, fill="#AAA", tags="thirdtag")
         secondText = canvas.create_text(110, 90, text="Final Choice")
         canvas.delete(square)
    
    def onThirdClick(secondsquare, secondText):
         canvas.delete(secondsquare)
         canvas.delete(secondText)
    
    root = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=200)
    mainbutton = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 30, 100, 60, width=5, fill="#666", tags="mainbuttontag")
    manibuttontxt = canvas.create_text(55, 45, text="Main Menu", tags="mainbuttontag")
    canvas.tag_bind("mainbuttontag", "<ButtonPress-1>", onObjectClick)
    canvas.tag_bind('secondtag', "<ButtonPress-1>", onSecondClick)
    canvas.tag_bind('thirdtag', "<ButtonPress-1>", onThirdClick)
    canvas.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory. `square` is a local variable rather than a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do what I needed to do... I have dropped trying to use the canvas variable and used the "tags" option to choose what to delete upon a click action.

Here is the sample code I came up with. Feel free to butcher it if you think I am wrong or if there is a better way to approach this,

```
from Tkinter import * 
txt2 = "Second Square"
txt3 = "Third Square" 
global square
global mainbuttontxt

def onObjectClick(event):
        square = canvas.create_rectangle(40, 50, 150, 100, width=1, fill="#BBB", tags="secondtag")
        squaretxt = canvas.create_text(90,70, text=txt2, tags="secondtag")
        canvas.delete("mainbuttontag")

def onSecondClick(event):
        secondsquare = canvas.create_rectangle(60,70,160,110, width=1, fill="#AAA", tags="thirdtag")
        secondText = canvas.create_text(110, 90, text=txt3, tags="thirdtag")
        canvas.delete("secondtag")

def onThirdClick(event):
        canvas.delete("thirdtag")
        mainbutton = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 30, 100, 60, width=5, fill="#666", tags="mainbuttontag")
        manibuttontxt = canvas.create_text(55, 45, text="Main Menu", tags="mainbuttontag")


root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=200)
mainbutton = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 30, 100, 60, width=5, fill="#666", tags="mainbuttontag")
manibuttontxt = canvas.create_text(55, 45, text="Main Menu", tags="mainbuttontag")
canvas.tag_bind("mainbuttontag", '<ButtonPress-1>', onObjectClick)
canvas.tag_bind('secondtag', '<ButtonPress-1>', onSecondClick)
canvas.tag_bind('thirdtag', '<ButtonPress-1>', onThirdClick)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```